# How to design a flexible payload for a microservice?

Tags: microservices

I am currently trying to implement a Generic solution for common processes, and this solution will require supporting different payloads for each specific usage.

I am not aware of a way to define a flexible payload, my approach will be that I will use all the fields needed by each process in one common Data Model, and set them to null if they are not relevant for the current usecase of the microservice.

```
public class Request {
    private Integer processId;

    private String process1Var1;
    private String process1Var2;

    private String process2Var1;
    private Integer process2Var2; 
}
```

Is there any better/cleaner way to have a flexible payload? Thank you

Comment: Sure, one string. Pack it with json. Also, it's hard to set integers to null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how much interoperability and visibility you want.

## Data Language

Take your pick:

- JSON
- XML
- YAML
- etc...

These languages have a truly large and robust third-party tooling, and language support/libraries, making it trivial to implement and trivial to read, you need only think up and layout the data appropriately.

If the data needs to change, just change it, all consumers can read it even if they don't know how to handle it productively. But you may need to revisit any preserved instances and migrate them.

Storage is usually a `string`.

## Data-Frame Languages

These require some extra work. They are usually in the binary form:

```
struct Frame
{
    //header fields that are in common between all frames
    int leadin; //< not needed in all situations, but a leadin allows you to thumbprint a frame and confirm that its likely one of your frames and not just random noise.
    int length; //< because even if you cannot identify the specific message, its handy to know how many bytes the message contains.
    int type; //< Some kind of enumeration naming the different kinds of frame
    byte version; //< Usually needs a versioning scheme so that the whole system can be redfined.
    date timestamp; //< not strictly necessary but meta-data in common between all frames can help
    //other meta-data

    //payload
    byte[] data; //< contains the actual payload, usually this would be cast into another data-structure based on the identified type/version of the frame

    //tail
    int leadout; //< not needed in all situations, but a leadout allows you to confirm that the frame was received intact, it also helps thumbprint the frame.
};
```

Such languages pop up all over the place:

- Zip files
- PNG files
- TCP wire format
- etc...

Data in this format has the advantage of being more compact, precisely what you need, and allows a level of interoperability (due to common fields and particularly to the size field and if present the leadin/leadout fields).

The downside is that it has to be custom tooled, and isn't as expressive as a straight Data Language.

Storage is usually a byte array.